# PDFBox - can we configure specific field using id or an xpath-like specification

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

My project requires to validate pdf files generated by an application. It may contain static as well dynamic text. For example a polilcyNo(1234567) generated by the application is shown on the pdf and we want to validate it.

Is it possible to configure the field through some kind of identifier and retrieve that field for validation rather than just extracting text and checking that text contains  '1234567'

Comment: As you don't say *how* that special text, e.g. the policy number, is added to the PDF, how can you expect us to say how you can extract it? Is the text in the page content? Or an AcroForm field? Is it probably even in an XFA form?

Comment: It is text in a page content - could be part of a paragraph or in a table format

Comment: Then you need text extraction. If you know the exact coordinates, you can filter by them. Otherwise you need some other indication where that content can be found, e.g. "after the text 'policyNo'".